# (Py)OpenCL: Fastest way to add floats to random positions in image?

Tags: opencl, raytracing, pyopencl

*Updated with different problem description. Bi-directional path tracing as suggested for my previous question is not an option.*

I have a Monte Carlo code that does some computation (physics simulation) with OpenCL. The host code is written in Python and PyOpenCL. The final result of the OpenCL kernel are coordinate tupels (x,y position + intensity/gray value) for an image (detector data). I have 3 vectors/1D arrays (one each for x position, y position and gray value). Each 1D array has about 1e6 to 1e8 entires, with x,y being int's and the gray values floats. The image to be created is a few 1000x1000 pixels (1e6 to 1e7 pixels).
Eventually I will need to create more than one image (with different coordinate tuples each) per run, so efficiency and low memory usage become important.

What would be the fastest way to generate a 2D array or image from these data? Multiple writes to the same position (x,y) do happen, and I can't find a good solution to do this in parallel or during the simulation (because of the possible simultaneous writes to the same position in the image).

What I currently do is to copy the 3 vectors/1D arrays back to the host, and do the image generation on the host in serial with an inline C function.

The most time-consuming parts of the code are the creation of output buffer arrays for the 3 1D arrays and then the copying from device to host when the kernel is done.
It would be great if I could either:
i) keep the data on the device and do the image generation with a 2nd kernel (tested, but very slow if done in serial)
ii) or if I could do the image generation while the kernel is running and thus get rid of the 1D arrays overall.

ii) is preferred, but I have no idea how to do that. Does write_image recognize if multiple work-items want to write to the same array index?
I have tested to parallelize i) by generating 2 independent 2D image arrays for two workgroups with 1 work item each, each item iterating over half of the 1D vectors (works), however for more work items and independent images the overhead to create the additional 2D arrays takes too long and consumes too much memory.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: update: Now I have tested i) with up to 32 compute units on my Radeon HD7950 GPU (using 32 independent images, which are added after the kernel is done), and it is still much slower than copying the data to the host first and use the CPU. Data transfer takes too much time. Still no idea how to do ii).

Answer (score 2):

Python is not great for high performance applications, especially if it involves loops -- similarly to Matlab.

<strike>But if you want to stick to Python and parallelize your code, the best way is to use PyCuda for which you can have one thread per pixel and run the computations on the GPU.</strike>

Note that the most efficient raytracing is *backward* raytracing, that sends rays from the camera toward the scene (for instance, one ray per pixel), so that you are sure to not waste rays that would otherwise never reach the camera.  Maybe the first thing before trying to parallelize your code, is to understand and implement a more efficient algorithm.

If you want global effects, you can look into (bidirectional) path tracing and photo mapping.

Comment: Or you could.. you know.. use OpenCL (which the OP already uses) to do everything on the GPU, instead of suggesting CUDA. Magic bullet for the loss..

Comment: ouch indeed, thanks - for some reason I read PyOpenCV (which I found odd in the context). My remarks about choosing a better suited algorithm still applies though.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, I don't do ray-tracing for computer graphics. My code is an x-ray propagation/simulation code, hence the Monte Carlo approach. I have quite a few random numbers involved (random ray origin at source, angle, x-ray energy, intensity, etc), and there is a mirror involved with ray-dependent reflection properties, so starting from the camera is not an option.

Comment: Why isn't it an option and what is specific for x-rays ? To my knowledge, x-rays satisfy Helmholtz reciprocity, and what you want is the same as what is done in CG. The best you can do,imho, is bidirectional path tracing, which is unbiased, and accounts for reflectors etc. It generates rays from the light sources and receptors, and you will gain a much higher improvement in term of quality for the same time (or faster for the same quality) than by parallelizing your code. Monte Carlo integration improves with the sqrt of the number of samples, so with 16 cores you'll get at best 4x improvement

Comment: I have to think about that. What I need as well is a good representation of photon statistics at the camera. The source in the real world is photon-limited, so it would be great if the simulation could include that. Don't know if path tracing would work...